# How can a master thesis in STEM approach the level of a doctoral thesis?

Tags: phd, graduate-school, thesis

Can someone shed some light on the subtle difference between a master thesis and a doctoral thesis so that a master student can arrange his or her research strategy geared to produce work at near the level doctoral thesis assuming that time is not a factor.

Note: I come from an engineering background so research encompasses both theoretical work (derivation of equations, modeling) and experiments (software analysis, characterization of physical devices)

Please also feel free to comment on the feasibility of actually producing PhD level dissertation at the master level

Comment: In some fields the main difference is simply the requirement of original research. Could you specify your field?

Comment: + 1 to Tobias; knowing your particular field in STEM will help you get a more accurate answer. Generally speaking, it is entirely possible but quite unlikely for a MSc thesis to be at the same level of PhD thesis. Even if you say time is not a factor, I would assume that it would wasteful from the student's perspective. MSc requirements are easier to fulfill than PhD requirements so I do not see the reason to invest so much time and effort without getting an actual PhD.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it: "so that a master student can arrange his or her research strategy geared to produce work at near the level doctoral thesis assuming that time is not a factor." You want to produce research which is at the level of a PhD thesis and which takes more time than an ordinary master's thesis.  So....don't you want to be a PhD student?  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Requirements vary widely from program to program and from institution to institution.

Some programs require a doctoral candidate to publish in a peer-reviewed journal (probably most programs would take issue if you didn't publish or present anything). Most programs (or committees) wouldn't let you graduate with a PhD unless you published at least once, and would expect at least twice.

My general hunch is that a doctoral dissertation (rarely called a "doctoral thesis") is generally several times longer. While a masters thesis might be 20-50 pages, dissertations are routinely 80-150 pages...and sometimes way more (this varies widely by discipline, by the academic culture of your institution, and by your committee). Some programs allow the doctoral candidate to use three publications, combined into a single manuscript, as his or her dissertation.

Lastly, the doctoral degree is intended to show that the recipient can perform original research. Masters degrees have a wide variety of understandings or intents, from "the recipient passed our comprehensive exams", to "the recipient performed an original research project and published it".

**Whatever you've done for your masters thesis, focus on research for your PhD.** Learn what interesting questions are in your field and choose one to focus on. Read the background literature to learn how others have approached the problem. Work with your advisor and committee to figure out how you can contribute something new and useful to the field, and then do it. Publish your findings in a journal; present your results and network with peers at conferences. Finally, write it all up in your dissertation, defend it, and graduate. That sums up getting a PhD. The rest are details.

You may find [this page](http://www.enago.com/blog/thesis-vs-dissertation-depends-on-where-you-are/) useful.

Comment: There's another few steps to getting your PhD: either you, your advisor, or somebody at a conference will bring you to the breaking point sometime during your time as a grad student. At these times, commiserate with your fellow grads, encourage each other, drink beer (if that's your thing) or start a new hobby on the side to maintain your sanity. Rinse and repeat.

Comment: Just a nitpick, but I somehow feel that in "this varies widely by discipline", it should be emphasized that "this" refers to both indicated number ranges. In any case (concerning that you commented on your own answer), you should always be able to edit your answers to add additional information later on.

Comment: "probably all would take serious issue if you didn't" A not-insignificant number of students are funded by grants from industry, with the requirement that their thesis is "sealed" for a number of years before being made publicly. There would obviously be no expectation that they should publish if they are working on something confidential.

Comment: _rarely called a "doctoral thesis"_ — I hear "thesis" and "dissertation" used interchangeably all the time.

Comment: 80 pages sounds more like masters thesis to me :-)

Comment: @MJeffryes: As far as I know, things are less binary than what your comment sounds like. The thesis as a whole may well have to be sealed, but the reasons for that might vary - e.g., some companies require secrecy especially or only if any of their data or processes are mentioned, which may be the case in the thesis, but does not necessarily apply to every single publication on a single aspect of the research. Also, some universities aim for upholding the scientific spirit of publishing one's results in a way that they flat-out refuse to sign any blanket agreements for sealing whatever is ...

Comment: ... created during a PhD, and insist on deciding on a per-case basis, which again can mean that at least some papers are published as a basis for the thesis.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper My point is just that there are plenty of cases where students do not publish, and this is not a problem for their PhD, not that no students with a sealed thesis publish. At least in the UK, there is generally no requirement to publish in order to graduate, the thesis is judged purely on its own merits.

Comment: "Some programs require a doctoral candidate to publish in a peer-reviewed journal (probably all would take serious issue if you didn't)." This is wildly false at the level of all STEM disciplines. Please scope your statement accordingly and include information about why or how you believe this to be the case.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: You mentioned that some countries (e.g. India) do impose hard limits in your comment here: http://tinyurl.com/m5shkc6. See the discussion here (http://tinyurl.com/kfnbtpj), here (http://tinyurl.com/mwt383d) or here (http://tinyurl.com/mpnbq2y) for some further discussion.

Comment: Right.  To be more clear, what is wildly false is "probably all would take serious issue if you didn't".  Also "Most programs (or committees) wouldn't let you graduate with a PhD unless you published at least once, and would expect at least twice." depends what you mean by "most" and what programs you are ranging over.  If by this you mean more than 50% of all STEM PhD programs in the world, I don't know whether it's true and I would be interested to know.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Gotcha. I would also really be interested to see this tabulated out!